# Android - Dynamically changing background color of a layout

Tags: android

I want to change the background color of the `coordinatorLayout` every second.
But, what I find is that, the color `coordinatorLayout` changes from the initial color `RED` to directly the last color i.e. `#09FF00` in the `COLORS` array. The intermediate color don't show up in the layout, though they get logged in the `LogCat`.
What am I doing wrong ?

```
public class ColorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static String COLORS [] = {"#FF0000", "#0000FF", "#09FF00"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detect);

    final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.fullscreenview);
    coordinatorLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            changeColor(coordinatorLayout);
        }
    }).start();

}

private void changeColor(final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (String color: COLORS) {
                Log.i("COLOR", color);
                coordinatorLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transition is happening way to fast. In your `run` method you iterate over the colors which is way too fast for the human eye to perceive it.

Instead you'll probably want to put the loop iteration over the colors inside your `Runnable`, like this (which will pause at every color for one second):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (final String color: COLORS) {
            Log.i("COLOR", color);
            changeColor(coordinatorLayout, color);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {/* ... */}
        }
    }
}).start();
```

And then change your `changeColor` method to this:

```
private void changeColor(final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, final String color) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            coordinatorLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How do I handle that ?

Comment: try to avoid putting delay on ui thread otherwise you will get ANR dialog.

Comment: @Yasir Ali The delay is not on the UI thread, but inside the background `Runnable`. Correct me if I'm wrong here...

Comment: sorry i got confused with loop as question has similar loop in ui Runnable

Comment: My answer has also been a bit confusing ;) I've updated it for clarity.

Comment: @TR4Android - Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: No problem! Have fun coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is logically issue in your code

```
for (String color: COLORS) {
                Log.i("COLOR", color);
                coordinatorLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
            }
```

loop will execute so fast you won't realise intermediate colours. I would suggest change

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 int colorIndex = 0;
                do{
                try {
                    changeColor(coordinatorLayout,COLORS[colorIndex++]);
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
               }while(iteration < COLORS.length)   
            }
        }).start();


    private void changeColor(final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,final String color) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                Log.i("COLOR", color);
             coordinatorLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @mehrdad stack overflow complaining i don't have enough reputation to accept changes...:(

Answer (score 0):

if your timer logic trigger in every second then get single color from COLORS before calling changeColor then use it.

Like this...

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //get single color here
            //update color and pass it
            changeColor(coordinatorLayout, color);
        }
    }).start();


    private void changeColor(final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, color mcolor) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                Log.i("COLOR", mcolor);
                coordinatorLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(mcolor));

        }
    });
}
```